# how to set visual force page as default in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement that there is a user with particular profile and if he logs into the salesforce account, I want that he should be directly shifted to a visual force page. I tried to replace home tab with visual force page. But in profile this option is not editable. What I can do to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new "app". Apps are pretty much just sets of tabs (with exception of special stuff such as Service Cloud Console). In app you can define that there should be no home page, instead your visualforce (as a tab) would be added and marked as default landing page. Then you'd share this app with his profile and revoke access to other apps?

People can still add/remove tabs they wish to see in each app though so somebody might override your configuration.